# Expectation value for non-independent multivariate continues variables

Tags: probability, integration

I'm trying to calculate the expectation values $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ for the continuous pdf:

$$ f(x,y)=xe^{-y}\ , \ \,\ 0<x<y<\infty $$

Since the variables are depndent, I'm not sure if I can use the following method: $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x,y)dxdy$ to get:

$$ \int_{x}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}x^2e^{-y}dxdy$$

Because the result will be dependent on x. Am I in the right direction or should I do something else?

Also, for the covariance, can I use $cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$
I'm not sure if it's a general formula or I should be more careful in the continuous dependent case

Comment: In $$\int_{x}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}x^2e^{-y}dxdy$$ the integrand is correct, but the limits on the integral $\int_{x}^{\infty}$ are not correct.

Comment: Should it be $0$ to $\infty$? I'm not sure

Comment: The best way (in mu opinion) to figure out the limits on the integrals is to draw a picture of the region $0<x<y<\infty$.

Comment: Not sure I understand, it's basically the triangle above the $x=y$ line no? I miss something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $0<x<y<\infty$ corresponds to $x>0,y>x$ or $0<x<y, y>0$. Your integrals should be as follows:

$$E(XY)=\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty (xy)xe^{-y}dydx\\
E(X)=\int_0^\infty x\int_x^\infty xe^{-y} dydx\\
E(Y)=\int_0^\infty y\int_0^y xe^{-y}dxdy$$

For almost all if not all of them, you should use integration by parts setting $dv=e^{-y}dy$.